# Get QMenu's ActionRect for paint an image

Tags: qt, qmenu, qaction, qmenubar

```
QPainter p(this);

for (int i = 0; i < this->actions().count(); ++i)
 {

      QAction *action = this->actions().at(i);
      QRect actionRect = ...........
      QStyleOptionMenuItem opt;
      initStyleOption(&opt, action);
      opt.rect = actionRect;
      QString strPicPath="/h/downloads/tableviewenabledBackGroundImageId.jpg";
      QPixmap pic(strPicPath);
      pic=pic.scaled(opt.rect.size());
      opt.palette.setBrush(QPalette::Background,QBrush(pic));

      p.fillRect(opt.rect,opt.palette.background());

      style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_MenuItem, &opt, &p, this);
 }
```

i need get actionRect of QMenu for paint selected menu Item with out Using Qt's Stylesheet. 
thanks in advance

Comment: You could give a brief description of your problem, if you put it so probably close this question.

Comment: sorry for missunderstanding.... i need get actionRect of QMenu for paint selected menu Item with out Using Qt's Stylesheet.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44298888/edit) your question and add it there

Answer (score 0):

Try this->actionGeometry(QAction*), which should return the correct QRect. 
I used this in one of my programs, where it worked quite well.